# Mircrosoft Azure webservice deployment errror

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have created a web service in MVC4 Web API in Visual studio 2012. My web service is working fine in locahost(`localhost:49216/api/Authenticates`), but when I deploy this web service on the Microsoft azure account to access it globally, it displays the error `{"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred."}`. At the same time, when I access any html page (`myservice..azurewebsites.net/demo.html`) it's working fine. But when I call (`myservice..azurewebsites.net/api/Authenticates`), it's giving the error.

Comment: What is your client that you are trying from? Is it from JQuery, then it might be Cross Domain issue and to solve it you need to have CORS package installed. To check if this is the issue then try calling your API from a Fiddler.

Comment: Right now ,I am hitting in browser  please click   this  http://ptddemo.azurewebsites.net/Api/Property/GetpropTaxUserLogIn/?emailid=test@gmail.com&password=1234&authType=2&firstname=ausd&lastname=sjdfh

Comment: Your API is returning JSON. Couldn't you try debugging the controller action being hit to see what the error is?